# Check if people in a voice channel have turned on video (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Is there a way to check if all the people in a voice channel have turned on their videos
Ex - iterating over all the users in a voice channel to check if their video is on.

Comment: Please give us a clear explanation of your problem and please add what have you tried so far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try looking at this https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voicestate#discord.VoiceState.self_mute This is documentation for Voice State. It will tell you whether they are muted(by them not server) or not. I'm guessing video is fairly similar.